# Having trouble sending AND receiving information from a php file using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending some information to a php file that runs a query but I want to also retrieve some information from that php file at the same time. The php file executes fine but I can't get the json_encoded object.

Javascript function that sends a string and a number to a php file:

```
function open_close(){
    var status = encodeURIComponent(SelectedTicket["Status"]);
    var ticketNum = encodeURIComponent(SelectedTicket["TicketNum"]);
    var info = "Status="+status+"&TicketNum="+ticketNum;
    var http3 = createAjaxRequestObject();

    if (http3.readyState == 4) {
        if (http3.status == 200){
            alert("Ticket Updated!");  //This never gets hit                     
            getUpdatedTicket(JSON.parse(http3.responseText));
        }
    }

    http3.open("POST", "openClose.php", true);
    http3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http3.send(info);
}
```

PHP File that takes the string and number and updates a table

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    $status = $_POST["Status"];
    $num = $_POST["TicketNum"];
    $newStatus = " ";
    if(strcmp($status, "Open") == 0){
        $newStatus = "Closed";
    }
    elseif(strcmp($status, "Closed") == 0){
            $newStatus = "Open";
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET Status = \"$newStatus\" where TicketNum = $num ";
    $r = $conn ->query($sql) or trigger_error($conn->error."[$sql]");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tickets where TicketNum = $num";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

How can I retrieve the json_encoded object in the same javascript function?

Comment: The response from the server is in `http3.responseText`. Any tutorial on AJAX should explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a `readyState` listener to know when the request is done, and then get the data from the `responseText`

```
function open_close() {
    var status = encodeURIComponent(SelectedTicket["Status"]);
    var ticketNum = encodeURIComponent(SelectedTicket["TicketNum"]);
    var info = "Status=" + status + "&TicketNum=" + ticketNum;
    var http3 = createAjaxRequestObject();

    http3.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (http3.readyState == 4) {
            if (http3.status == 200) {
                console.log(http3.responseText); // <- it's there
            }
        }    
    }

    http3.open("POST", "openClose.php", true);
    http3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http3.send(info);
}
```